# Применение CSS-свойств к элеметам внутри определенного div

Tags: html, css

На странице есть список внутри `div`, выглядящий примерно так:

```
<div id="main-content" class="wiki-content">
<ol><li>
...
</li></ol>
</div>
```

Мне необходимо кастомизировать такой список, если он содержится в таком `div`, примерно таким способом:

```
ol {
    ...
}
ol li {
    ... 
}
ol li:before {
    ...
}
```

Как правильно описать это в файле стилей?

Comment: `.wiki-content ol li`.. В чём проблема то?

Comment: @Yuri проблема в том, что я не занимаюсь веб-дизайном :)

Comment: @approximatenumber, а при чем тут веб-дизайн? Обычная верстка\стилизация. Можно так: `.wiki-content ol li { ... }` , а можно и по id - `.#main-content ol li { ... }`

Comment: да и не верстальщик тоже, просто появилась проблема отображения списков в JIRA, а официальный совет от Atlassian не работает. Посмотрел в исходник, увидел `div`, а как правильно описать css, не знаю.

Comment: @approximatenumber , ну вот на будущее https://webref.ru/layout/learn-html-css/getting-to-know-css

Comment: @Elena так зачем вы помогаете на SO? Сразу бы прайс писали. А вообще http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте в селекторе класс `.wiki-content`. Выглядеть это будет так:

```
.wiki-content ol {
    // Ваши стили
}

.wiki-content li {
    // Ваши стили
}

.wiki-content li:before {
    // Ваши стили
}
```

Если у вас используется препроцессор, к примеру Less, можно сделать еще проще:

```
.wiki-content {

    ol {
        // Ваши стили
    }

    li {
        // Ваши стили
        &:before {
            // Ваши стили
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, решается легко и просто, действительно. Мне надо было просто больше почитать документацию. Но т.к. времени на это нет, и работа никак не связана с CSS/HTML, то понадобилась помощь stackoverflow. Спасибо.

Comment: @approximatenumber, обращайтесь. Как говориться "Не стыдись спросить, не знать - еще постыдней!".

Comment: @approximatenumber, на id принято завязывать JS, а стилизовать лучше всегда через class.